# Из локального репозитория создать удаленный репозиторий на github

Tags: git, github, git-push

Вопрос в следующем, можно ли на github.com создать папку для репозитория git командами с локального компьютера. Т.е. должны ли работать такие команды:

```
git remote add shot_link_name "https://github.com/user/myproject.git" 
git push -u shot_link_name master
```

Если github.com у пользователя user папка myproject.git отсутствует. 
Интересно знать нужно ли каждый раз заходить на сервер и сначала создавать удаленный репозиторий и клонировать его или можно сначала делать все локально, а по необходимости запушить все на сервер. Заранее спасибо всем ответившим.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Судя по выдаче гугла на запрос

> [github create repository from local](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=github%20create%20repository%20from%20local)

Можно воспользовать API гитХаба и послать запрос чрез него для создания репозитория как это описано на [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10325316/3212712)

```
curl -u 'USER' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"REPO"}'
```

Замените `USER` на ваш юзерНэйм а `REPO` на имя нового репозитория. После отправки этого запроса вам надо будет ввести пароль от аккаунта и репозиторий будет создан.

После чего можно добавить новый `remote` для локального репозитория и запушить всё что нужно:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:USER/REPO.git
git push origin master
```

Comment: Есть специальный CLI ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin, гугл об этом не знает)

Answer (score 5):

Да, это можно сделать при помощи Github API.

```
curl -u 'username:password' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"название_проекта","description":"Описание"}'
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/название_проекта
и т.д.
```

Answer (score 4):

Есть отличный CLI для GitHub, называется [Hub](https://hub.github.com/). Не буду приводить всех инструкций по установке и настройке (они есть по ссылке), ограничусь примером. Следите за руками!

```
hub create
```

И это всё!

1. Hub создаёт удалённый репозиторий GitHub для вашего пользователя, имеющий то же имя, что и корневая директория проекта;
2. настраивает его как remote текущего репозитория;
3. пушит содержимое.

Разумеется, есть параметры, позволяющие задать другое имя, описание, создать приватный репозиторий и т.п.

`man hub` (подразумевается `alias git=hub`):

> git create [NAME] [-p] [-d DESCRIPTION] [-h HOMEPAGE]
>
> Create a new public GitHub repository from the current git repository and add remote origin at "git@github.com:USER/REPOSITORY.git"; USER is your GitHub username and REPOSITORY is the current working directory name. To explicitly name the new repository, pass in NAME, optionally in ORGANIZATION/NAME form to create under an organization you're a member of. With -p, create a private repository, and with -d and -h set the repository's description and homepage URL, respectively.