# Создание удаленного репозитория через консоль

Tags: git, github

```
$ git remote add test https://github.com/prochka/test2
$ git remote -v
test    https://github.com/prochka/test2 (fetch)
test    https://github.com/prochka/test2 (push)
$ git remote show test
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/prochka/test2/' not found
```

Не находит созданный репозиторий. На GitHub ничего не создается. Подскажите, в чем дело?
Все взято [отсюда](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8)

Comment: [Способ раз](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/584084/), [способ два](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/504578/)...

Comment: $ curl -u 'prochka' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"test3"}'
Enter host password for user 'prochka':
Через API нет возможности ввести пароль - не работает ни одна клавиша

Comment: Все вопросы - в ту тему. Но сначала всё внимательно почитать. Кстати, из чего следует что клавиши не работают? Скорее всего просто при вводе пароля вводимые символы не отображаются и курсор не двигается.

Comment: @PinkTux посмотрел API и сделал так:  curl -u 'username:password' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"название_проекта","description":"Описание"}'

Comment: Установить `hub`, потом [`hub create`.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/584631/181472)